# Need Help With Hibernate/SQL Query Count Logic

Tags: sql, hibernate, count

I have the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT w.name, count(*) FROM widgets AS w
JOIN w.entity AS e
JOIN e.article AS a
JOIN a.document AS d
WHERE d.id IN (<document ids>)
GROUP BY w.name
```

The problem is that `count(*)` returns the number of widget-entity associations. Instead, what I'm looking for is the number of unique widget names, per article or document.

Here's an example:

Let's say that I have two entities: `cat` and `dog`.
I also have two distinct widgets that share the same name, `foo`.
Each of the `foo` widgets is associated with one of the entities (one with `cat`, the other with `dog`).
Both `cat` and `dog` are associated with the article `animals`.
I'd like the count returned by this query to be only 1 (because the widget name `foo` is only found once in the article `animals`), instead of 2.

I've tried placing other things in the count clause, like `count(d.id)`, with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha, I figured it out!

Since I'm using MSSQL in the backend, I can do this: `count(DISTINCT a.id)`